# if to check whenever a radio is checked or not

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, radio-button, checked

I output a bunch of input checkboxes and radio buttons in a form using php like this

```
if($product['type']==1)
{
    $selector = "<input type='checkbox' class='product' data-price='".$product['price']."' name='prod_".$product['pid']."' id='prod_".$product['pid']."' value='".$product['pid']."'>";
}
elseif($product['type']==2)
{
    $selector = "<input type='radio' required class='product' data-price='".$product['price']."' name='cat_".$product['id']."' id='cat_".$product['id']."' value='".$product['pid']."'>";   
}
```

As you can see these input boxes hold a `data-price` element and a class of `product`

Im then using jquery to listen for when elements with the product class change like this

```
$(".product").change(function(){
    var product = $(this); 
    var price = product.data('price');
    if(product.is(':checked')) {    
       total = total + price;
    } else {
       total = total - price;
    }
});
```

My problem is that the above never reaches the else clause when the `product` var is a radio button. It works without problems when the `product` var is a checkbox. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: You can use `.each()` on `.product`, and find out the `total` during each change event

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $(".product").change(function(){   
    var price = $(".product").attr('data-price');    
    if ($(".product").attr("checked")){
       total = total + price;
    }
    else
    {
       total = total - price;
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: This always return false

Answer (score 0):

**Obviously it will not reach**. because `radio` button will not have `unchecked` event unlike `checkbox`. So you need to write a event for `radio` button to `uncheck` it and write a click event instead. So make below changes to your radio button while adding and some `JS` event change as below:

```
else if($product['type']==2)
{
    $selector = "<input type='radio' name="foo" required class='product' data-price='".$product['price']."' name='cat_".$product['id']."' id='cat_".$product['id']."' value='".$product['pid']."'>"; 
   makeRadiosDeselectableByName('foo');// Call after appending  
}
```

Now Add one custom JS

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/EtNXP/1562/)** to make `radio` selectable and deselectable

```
var makeRadiosDeselectableByName = function(name){
    $('input[name=' + name + ']').click(function() {
        if($(this).data('previousValue') == 'true'){
            $(this).attr('checked', false)
        } else {
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').data('previousValue', false);
        }

        $(this).data('previousValue', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });
};
```

Now your function should work

```
$(".product").click(function(){
    var product = $(this); 
    var price = product.data('price');
    if(product.is(':checked')) {    
       total = total + price;
    } else {
       total = total - price;
    }
});
```